# Do I have job options now?

Tags: employment

I'm 23 years old and no work experience and I also got arrested a couple of years ago for a misdemeanor. Even though I didn't get convicted and my arrest was expunged I still see it as I still have a criminal record. I was wondering do I have job options now or is my life over?

Comment: Options for what? What industry or career? What kind of job? Please narrow this down to help you better, as this is currently a bit broad IMHO

Comment: @DarkCygnus sounds like the OP is just looking for reassurance. OP --- you're life is not over. Go to school and get a degree and start proving that you learned from your mistakes and will no again that route. Good luck

Comment: Related / duplicates: [How should I address a non-violent criminal record when applying for jobs?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/12579), [Entering the professional workforce with a criminal record](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/77450), [Convicted felon looking for a job](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/48494), [Have job offer from major tech firm. Will 'Driving under the influence' (DUI) from 3 years ago be a show stopper?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/32297) I'm far from a lawyer, but I thought expunge = remove from record - you might want to investigate that.

Comment: **Your life is definitely not over**.  Heck, it's barely begun.  I can understand why you feel the way you do, and you may catch some flack for your past mistakes along the way, but seriously, the only way you can fail is if you stop trying.  There are employers out there who can look past a criminal record (especially one without conviction) and those are the good, open-minded employers you WANT to work for anyway.

Comment: " Even though I didn't get convicted and my arrest was expunged I still see it as I still have a criminal record." - celan up your delusions. Obviously you do not have a criminal record.

Comment: As @TomTom Said, it was expunged so you do not have a criminal record.

Comment: I've had to start "at the bottom" many times - you should have no problems unless (A) you're lazy (B) you eat a high carb. diet.  As long as you're not (A) or (B), you'll have no problems.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you still have options but you're going to have to start at the bottom to prove you are reliable.  Get a job working at a gas station, in the kitchen of a restaurant washing dishes, or some similar menial job.  Those places tend to have such high turnover that they will take basically anyone willing to work.  If you see a Help Wanted sign, you submit an application.  You don't have the luxury of being picky.

Apply, apply, apply.  You may have to apply for dozens of jobs but it only takes one to accept you and then you can start building that work history.  Maybe you can advance to a supervisor position or start getting an education in your spare time.  If you are willing to show up on time and work hard, you've already got an advantage over many people out there.

At this point, it's totally up to you whether you sink or swim, but nobody is going to give you a job if you don't start looking.

Comment: I concur with all of the above.  Also, you are in charge of your own story.  If your arrest was expunged, at least in the USA, you can truthfully answer "nope, no criminal record" on any job application.